# Why are user environment variables sometimes not expanded?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, environment-variables

I set a user environment variable FOO=bar via the control panel.

[image]

I then open 2 cmd windows. The first from the start button, the other from the context (shift+right-click) menu of my working directory, and type `echo %FOO%`.

The first prints `bar`. The other prints `%FOO%`

[image]

Why are the outputs different & is there a way to access user environment variables from every cmd window?

Comment: I can't replicate that. I get the var expanded in both "double-click cmd" and "right-click->open cmd" versions.

Comment: While the involved variable was `%path%`, I think [this](http://superuser.com/a/917186/362853) is relevant in this case

Comment: @MarcB I don't have admin privileges. Try logging in with a restricted account to see if you can replicate it that way perhaps.

Comment: I didn't set a system env var, just a per-user one. or do you mean "right-click->open" as in open an admin shell?

Comment: Sorry @MarcB, it's sometimes hard to explain oneself clearly regarding these things. _Shift+right-click_ was a reference to how I opened the second cmd window. That is: from windows explorer, when I right-click a _folder_ while holding the shift key, a context menu appears allowing me to _Open command window here_. I did _not_ mean _right-click -> Run as administrator_. I also did not set a system variable, just a user one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on the same problem.

```
c:\SetX test NOT
c:\echo test=%test% fail.
test= fail.

c:\start %comspec%
Microsoft Wind..er..DOS [Version 6.1.7601]
c:\echo test=%test% fail.
test= fail.

Start -> run -> cmd
echo test=%test% fail.
test=NOT fail.
```

A win-r macro would work but prefer quiet / non-intrusive solution.

I tried by using schtasks /run  but it kept the old env.

There's probably a command to launch with the new env.

Nirsoft or sysinternals probably has something...

Still looking.

*** MSalters answered OP correctly, inheritance issue.

The command-prompt-here inherited the explorer's old environment.

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
start explorer
```

Then a new context-menu command-prompt-here should work.

Comment: MSalters did answer part of my question but the most informative answer I've seen is the [link](http://superuser.com/a/917186) MC ND posted in the comments of my original question. I'll accept this answer though as it goes on to suggest a solution for the context menu approach. For my own purposes however, I think I'll just accept defeat and navigate to the folder the old fashioned way with the prompt that works. Killing processes & changing registry values wouldn't actually make life more convenient in my particular case.

Comment: OK.   "Launch Folder in a Separate Process" might be the issue.  http://serverfault.com/questions/694629/environment-variable-clientname-scope-on-terminal-server   But I've seen posts like that that where the 'solution' was actually starting a new explorer or cmd prompt, not whatever else they did.

Answer (score 1):

how are you setting the variable? 
I believe you may be setting it as a "CMD variable", which scope is only valid for the current session.

For a persistent variable you should use SETX command:

```
SETX FOO bar
```

Please visit the following links for detailed information between SET and SETX commands:

- http://ss64.com/nt/set.html
- http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html

Comment: I set the variable from the control panel (question updated).

Comment: Using setx does persist variables between sessions, but in my case the variable still does not expand in the _newly opened_ context menu cmd session.

Answer (score 0):

User environment variables are **inherited**. Each process gets them on creation from its parent. Changing them will affect the current process and its **future** children.